# SQL - Remove Parenthesis from Phone Number

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to remove parenthesis from the area code of a number. I'm able to do so but when I try to concatenate the two Replace functions, the numbers repeat with only one parenthesis removed.

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT HomePhone, REPLACE(HomePhone, '(', '') + 
REPLACE(HomePhone, ')', '') AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Employees
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwsyj.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nest don't add

```
Replace(Replace(HomePhone,')',''),'(','')
```

Look at how the function replace works.  It expects string With Text To Evaluate, string to replace, string to replace with)

By adding them you should be getting the number listed twice, but if the data type isn't long enough it may be truncating values.  by nesting you're telling the system to replace the ) and then use that string w/o the ) to have the ( replaced with ''.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate in this way, you must use the concat function in SQL. Or use thus:

```
SELECT HomePhone, REPLACE(REPLACE(HomePhone, ')', ''), '(', '') AS Expr1 FROM dbo.Employees
```